# PIP mode in Agora group video call

Tags: ios, objective-c, agora.io, picture-in-picture

I have implemented agora group video chat  functionality in iOS and now i want to implement PIP mode in agora group video chat, so please him me regarding this

Thank you everyone

Comment: Please update the question with any information about what you have attempted, any code that you have would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Dhanraj. Have you figured it out? I'll take the same shot in React Native

Comment: @Rafael Cavalcante have you implemented pip mode on agora video chat? i got struck on the same.

Comment: Hi @MathanG! Unfortunately it's not possible. You'll need a pure <Video> output to tell iOS/Android to handle it as PIP.

The only way i understand to make something similar is enable the Agora Video in a fixed component that floats above the app (won't work if the video is inside a screen/route). TLDR: We dropped the PIP feature (we're using React Native)

Answer (score 0):

To leverage Picture in Picture on iOS with Agora.io, you need to use a custom video source or a custom video render, depending on which video stream you wish to view.

Since there is not enough information to provide any code, perhaps this tutorial and GitHub samples will help point you in the right direction.

using PIP with a custom video player:
https://medium.com/@halilozel1903/how-to-use-picture-in-picture-pip-in-swift-585a59f6cc8c

Agora Advanced Video Sample apps: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/tree/master/iOS%26macOS